# Convergence of a reciprocal sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $x_n \to x$ with $x_n \neq 0\quad \forall n, \space x\neq 0$. Prove that $\frac{1}{x_n} \to \frac{1}{x}$.

How is this for a proof?

$x_n \to x \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad\exists N = N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N \quad |x_n - x|<\varepsilon$

For $n\geq N(1) \quad |x_n - x| < 1 \implies |x_n| \geq 1 + |x| \implies \frac{1}{|x_n|} \leq \frac{1}{1+|x|}$

So given any $\varepsilon >0$, for every $n\geq \max\{N(1), N(\varepsilon |x|(1+|x|))\}$ we have $\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{x}\right| = \left|\frac{x-x_n}{x\cdot x_n}\right| = \frac{|x_n - x|}{|x||x_n|} < \frac{\varepsilon |x|(1+|x|)}{|x|(1+|x|)} = \varepsilon \implies \frac{1}{x_n} \to \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: looks good to me, is this just a proof verification question?

Comment: $|x_n - x| < 1 \not\Rightarrow |x_n| \geq 1 + |x|.$ @person

Comment: @AnneBauval, oh oops it goes the other way, I did not read it carefully. Better to use the Cauchy sequences are bounded trick I guess.

Comment: Cauchy sequences are off topic. Better look at the proposed duplicate.